# How does the blockchain.info shared receive work?

Tags: blockchain.info, money-laundering, mixing

I understand the concept of a mixer and have succesfully used Blockchain.info wallet's shared send feature. The shared receiving address however confuses me. I assumed that one needs to click "new shared address" and then send the coins to the new address that is created. However after testing with tiny amounts I got really weird results, such as coins disappearing, mixing not working etc.

I am asking for a detailed step-by-step guide on how to use the feature as well as an explanation of the mechanism behind it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Shared Recieve is also a mixer. When you get a new shared address, it will also show the "Forward To" address which will be one of your main addresses. If anyone sends bitcoins to that shared address, Blockchain.info will send them through its mixer then send it to the "Forward To" address. However, there are transactions costs and blockchain.info's 1.5% fee. It's meant for bigger amounts.

Comment: Thanks. I did know everything you said but apparently I had had trouble applying that knowledge to the wallet's interface - reading your post and thinking everything through for the millionth time finally worked. I hadn't realized that the wallet makes the current main address shared and that's what confused me. Now I understand. Thanks!